# Ask help for official Windows Phone channels. Are you against?

Tags: discussion

What you guys think about talk with The official [Windows Phone Support twitter](https://twitter.com/#!/WinPhoneSupport/), Windows Phone Evangelist [Ben Rudolph](https://twitter.com/#!/BenThePCGuy/) and some sites like [WPCentral](http://www.wpcentral.com/), [Windows Phone Daily](http://www.windowsphonedaily.com/) and [WMPoweruser](http://wmpoweruser.com/) about this Windows Phone Stack Exchange?

We need more people here according to [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20757/windows-phone). We are receiving less than 3 questions per day and even with 99% questions answered we only receive about 200 visits by day.

This is not healthy number for a beta Stack Exchange.

I spread for every people I know that have a WP but here in Brazil it is still starting. We have only 3 WP models and Microsoft looks like didn't start here for real.

I can't reach so many people but maybe with help of these guys we can reach more people.

Edit: **If you are against please downvote. Or else I will try contact them.**

Edit2: **Please follow this link to continue: [Where have we already tried to promote our Windows Phone site?](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/where-have-we-already-tried-to-promote-our-windows-phone-site)**

Comment: They say... **No we already have, Yes you can get**; so, let's try this. We should however keep track of who contacted which sites, so we don't send duplicate requests. For example, someone already poked a famous Twitter account in another meta post...