# Where have we already tried to promote our Windows Phone site?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

As we don't want to bother other people / communities / sites with asking them several time to promote us, we will want to keep track which ones we tried so that we instead spent time on trying to get promoted by other communities. This should lead in more effective promotion and thus, a more active community...

Comment: Does wearing a StackExchange T-Shirt to one of the WP7 dev camps count? ;)

Answer (score 3):

I think promoting on any related sites is a good idea, as long as we do so politely and don't spam sites.

Probably a good idea to announce in this post any specific places that you will contact (and update on the status). This way we can avoid lots of people contacting the same site and annoying the admins.

Comment: Good idea avoid contact the guys more than once.

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to edit this answer to add the sites where you have promoted.

- http://forums.hardwarezone.com.sg/
- http://twitter.com/mingfeiy
- [Heathcliff74](http://www.wp7roottools.com/) (homebrew dev but passionate)
- [WindowsPhoneSupport](https://twitter.com/#!/WinPhoneSupport) on twitter
- [Ben Rudolph](https://twitter.com/#!/BenThePCGuy/) (Microsoft Windows phone evangelist)